# return model with lowercase columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails program that is accessing a legacy database with UPPERCASE table columns.

I want to be able to type user.firstname rather than user.FIRSTNAME

How do I make ActiveRecord retrieve the lowercase version of these column names to allow me to use lowercase attributes in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to change the column names with migrations. Otherwise you will have to change the gems that you are using and then pack them in vendor/gems to keep as they degrade.

1. script/generate migration down_case_table_names_and_columns
2. write the migration
3. rake db:migrate

For each table:

```
rename_table :OLD_NAME, :new_name
```

For each column:

```
rename_column :COLUMN_NAME, :column_name
```

## problems

You might not have to change the name of the tables, fyi - you might get an error about changing the table names. I have never changed a table name so I don't know if this will work. In therms of changing column names there will be no problem.

Comment: I dont think changing the column names is an option, as the database is accessed by other software that may break if I change them. Surely there must be a way for the model to convert all attributes to lower case?

Comment: Your going about this the wrong way. You should not change active record to suit a bad database. dumb you mysql and then change the table names.

Comment: If you do want to change active record what you need to do is first unpack the active record gem. Then go search around find out how it is mapping ruby Models.

Comment: It should be easy because active record maps ruby models to database tables by pluralizing the table name ie post.rb posts_table

Comment: And then you just need to use `.downcase`; but like I said this is surly the wrong way to go. the tables are the problem, not active record.

Comment: after some investigating, I discovered the other system would not break if i used lowercase table names so this was the best solution as suggested. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best way to deal with this if changing column names isn't feasible: https://github.com/reidmix/legacy_mappings